# Como relacionar un string con el nombre de una función?

Tags: python

Me gustaría poder llamar a una función cuyo nombre viene dado por un string. Por ejemplo, si el código fuera:

```
lista = ['funcion1', 'funcion2']

def funcion1():
   x = 1
   print (x)

def funcion2():
   pass

def llamada(nombre):
    if nombre in lista: # el nombre que sea
      nombre() # Llamar a la función que coincida con el nombre

llamada(funcion1)
```

Lo que quiero es que la función *llamada* sea capaz de relacionar *nombre* con el texto que hay dentro de *"funcion1"*, para así llamar a la función que tenga ese nombre concreto.
La lista tiene que ser así (con string) porque en mi código no voy a saber esos nombres a priori, si no que se van añadiendo, por lo que no puedo definirlos de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Te propondré dos formas de lograr lo que pretendes.

#### Acceder al diccionario de variables globales (no recomendado)

En realidad, cuando creas una función, esta se almacena en una variable. Por ejemplo en este código:

```
def hola():
    print("hola mundo")
```

Creas una función que imprime "hola mundo" en la pantalla y la guardas dentro de la variable "hola".

En el caso de tu código, podrás hayar estas funciones en el ambito global.
Para acceder al diccionario de variables globales puedes usar el comando `globals()`.
`globals()` devuelve un diccionario cuya clave es el nombre de la variable en forma de cadena y de valor el valor de dicha variable.

Un ejemplo de lo que retorna esta magica función es el siguiente código:

```
variable = "valor"

def funcion():
    pass

print(globals())
```

Que produce:

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'C:\\Users\\Administrador.USUARIO-21G1KDL\\Desktop\\test.py', 'variable': 'valor', 'funcion': <function funcion at 0x036C4D18>}
```

Presta atención a los dos ultimos items del diccionario, que son la variable y la función que creamos en el código.

Sabiendo esto, es muy facil utilizarlo para acceder a la variable donde está guardada la función:

```
lista = ['funcion1', 'funcion2']

def funcion1():
   x = 1
   print (x)

def funcion2():
   pass

globales = globals()

def llamada(nombre):
    if nombre in lista: # el nombre que sea
      globales[nombre]() # Llamar a la función que coincida con el nombre

llamada("funcion1")
```

#### Crea tu propio diccionario (recomendado)

Puedes crear tu propio diccionario cuya clave sea el nombre de la función y el valor la función en sí. Asi funcionaría:

```
def funcion1():
   x = 1
   print (x)

def funcion2():
   pass

# Creo el diccionario luego de que se creen las funciones. Si no, daría un error por que las funciones no fueron creadas aun.
# Al no poner los parentesis al lado del nombre de la función, la función no es ejecutada en ningún momento.
dic = {"funcion1":funcion1, "funcion2":funcion2}

def llamada(nombre):
    if nombre in dic: # Si la función está en el diccionario, llama a dicha función
      dic[nombre]()

llamada("funcion1")
```

#### Unas palabras finales

Como habrás notado, en ambas soluciones el nombre de la función tiene que ir entre comillas. Esto es importante, ya que sino python creerá que intentas obtener el valor de una variable.
Si quieres más información sobre los diccionarios, te recomiendo esta pagina https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/. Aunque nunca está de más leer la documentación oficial de Python sobre los diccionarios.

Answer (score 0):

Para este objetivo se puede usar la función [getAttr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

> [getAttr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) Devuelve el valor del atributo nombrado del objeto. el
> nombre debe ser una cadena. Si la cadena es el nombre de uno de los
> atributos del objeto, el resultado es el valor de ese atributo. Por
> ejemplo, getattr (x, 'foobar') es equivalente a x.foobar. Si el
> atributo nombrado no existe, se devuelve el valor predeterminado si se
> proporciona; de lo contrario, se genera AttributeError.

Este es un ejemplo en el cual defines la clase y el nombre de la función

```
methodo_a_llamar = getattr(my_class, 'funcion1')
```

Ejemplo:

```
class my_class:

    lista = ['funcion1', 'funcion2']

    def funcion1():
        x = 1
        print (x)

    def funcion2():
        pass

    def llamada(nombre):
        if nombre in lista: # el nombre que sea
            nombre() # Llamar a la función que coincida con el nombre
 
methodo_a_llamar = getattr(my_class, 'funcion1')
methodo_a_llamar() #Aquí se llama la función
```